# Iterating the creation of objects in C++

Tags: c++, iteration

I want to be able to create N skyscrapers. Using an inputdata string, I would like to give them coordinate values of their X and Y positions. My main function I used "i" to demonstrate that I am trying to create as many skyscrapers as I can using the input data. Essentially, I would like to create N/3 skyscrapers and assign the input to coordinates for each.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;  
vector<int> inputData = {1, 4, 10, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 4, 11, 3, 2, 14, 5, 5}; 
int N = inputData.size();

class Buildings{
    public: 
        int yCoordinateLow; 
        int yCoordinateHigh; 
        int xCoordinateLeft; 
        int xCoordinateRight;

}; 

int main(){ 
    for(int i=0; i<N; i=i+3){
        Buildings skyscraper; 
        skyscraper.xCoordianteLeft = inputData.at(i); 
        skyscraper.yCoordianteLow = 0;
        skyscraper.yCoordinateHigh = inputData.at(i+1); 
        skyscraper.xCoordinateRight = inputData.at(i+2); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the i after skyscraper.yCoodrinateLow = 0 is a typo, but the question remains the same

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a proper [mre]. The typo you mention is not the only typo.

Comment: Don't you already create N/3 skyscrapers via the `for` loop? You would probably save them somewhere, e.g., in a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff Atwood once said: use the best tools money can buy. And those aren't even expensive: Visual Studio community edition is free. Such a proper IDE will tell you that the skyscraper is unused except for the assignments.

[image: Visual Studio tooltip]

Since you probably want to do something with those skyscrapers later, you should store them somewhere, e.g. in another vector.

```cpp
int main() {
    vector<Buildings> skyscrapers;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i + 3) {
        Buildings skyscraper{};
        skyscraper.xCoordinateLeft = inputData.at(i);
        skyscraper.yCoordinateLow = 0;
        skyscraper.yCoordinateHigh = inputData.at(i + 1);
        skyscraper.xCoordinateRight = inputData.at(i + 2);
        skyscrapers.push_back(skyscraper);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Other than that, I'd say the loop works fine as long as there are N*3 coordinates in the original vector.

If you e.g. implement a game, you would probably not hard code the skyscraper coordinates in a vector but rather read that data from a file, potentially per level.

Instead of doing all the error-prone coding, maybe you want to initialize the skyscrapers immediately

```cpp
vector<Buildings> skyscrapers = {{1,0,4,10}, {3,0,5,7}, {9,0,10,4}, {11,0,3,4}, {14,0,5,5}};
```

Comment: 'Not sure why you're pushing back onto the vector. The compiler *may* optimise this, but otherwise you're unnecessarily copying each element (plus, causing more copies in the resizing). Why not do it like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/WYYPhjqjq)?

Comment: @Elliott: I did that because I wanted that the OP still recognizes his parts of the code. I also provide an alternative solution which initializes the vector on its construction.

Comment: @Elliott: Your proposal does not keep the original class. It looks to me a bit like "why don't you rewrite everything from scratch"? The copying does not hurt for 5 objects. It's likely not a performance issue. I tend to not optimize unless I have a specific performance goal which is measurable.

Comment: I meant "*like* this." Not "*exactly* this." ie. I meant the way I initialise the vector size and iterate over its elements instead.